# Update ticks value of bootstrap slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider, bootstrap-slider

I am trying to update the value of bootstrap slider on some changes made on the app.

it is giving this `error : $(...).setAttribute is not a function` .

This issue is already being logged at gitHub
https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/issues/451

I have made the suggested changes

```
if (updateSlider === true) {
                    if (Array.isArray(this.options.ticks_labels) && this.options.ticks_labels.length > 0) { 
                        for (i = 0; i < this.options.ticks_labels.length; i++) {        
                            this.tickLabels[i].innerHTML = this.options.ticks_labels[i]
                        }
                    }
                }
```

and this is the code  which is updating it .

```
function UpdateMonthSlider(month)
{
    var updtdArray = GetTicksArray(month.MonthMin, month.MonthMax, monthStep);
    $('#monthSlider').setAttribute("ticks", updtdArray);
    $('#monthSlider').setAttribute("ticks_labels",  GetFormattedLabels(updtdArray, 'months', false));
    $('#monthSlider').slider('refresh');
}
```

Sample fiddle to show the error:
 [jsfiddle.net/mo6v9x7h/2](http://jsfiddle.net/mo6v9x7h/2/)

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle that reproduces the error?

Comment: it is a sample fiddle that I have posted, @ToddChaffee   http://jsfiddle.net/mo6v9x7h/2/

Comment: Check this link https://github.com/OnekO/bootstrap-slider/commit/b99bbff58f028d3b3331bc4fa8877023d8f1d674

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
$('#monthSlider').slider('setAttribute', 'ticks', updtdArray);
```

Comment: but there is a bug, that still is not foxed - https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/issues/451

Comment: Suggestions to try something can't pass for an answer. This should be a comment. Please wait until you've got sufficient rep to post comments.